# My first attempt of the water fluid simulation is not good

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Hello to each blender user!

Today, I tried to use a new feature: the water fluid simulation, but it didn't work, my result is different from one obtained in the tutorial that I'm following. I would like to understand why? This is the result that I should reach :

[image: result to reach]

Instead, this is [my result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vrhf_PTNauSF94QVJxZjJnWHM) :

These are some screenshot to show you what are the settings that I used to configure the water fluid simulation:

1. Domain:

[image: domain]

2) Emitter:

[image: emitter]

3) Shell:

[image: shell]

4) Tap:

[image: tap]

So, there is some wrong value that prevents the correct water scrolling. Do you know what is this ?

Comment: In 3 and 4 set to **volume**. Oh, and set inflow Z to zero. It should work.

Comment: This is probably not what the OP desired, because it would mean that the fuild is already present at the beginning. The first screenshot shows that the fluid should flow out of the smaller tunnel object above.

Comment: Could you provide a blend file please?

Comment: this is the result that I want to reach : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNaubFVVY1Y1bTExLVE/

Comment: the help given by @lukasz-40sth don't work as expected.

Comment: yes,here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNaucFBVdzBJNmhaVGM/

Comment: The Problem is that your inflow is inside the obstacle volume. You should place it inside the cutout of this tunnel obstacle (move it upwards the z axis).

Comment: you mean something like this ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauNXZoOUpqQ0VPLXc/ ; as you can see its better,but there are 2 errors again : 1) the water does not flow automatically,infact I should move the keyframes on the timeline by myself 2) 250 keyframes are not enough to make the water fall from the tap,instead on the tutorial they are enough.